# MVC controller does not recognize the choiche of my dropdown menu and application does not build

Tags: java, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have a dropdown menu in my thymeleaf view. It should call one of three methods through my MVC controller to implement sort my different criteria - name, rating ....

```
@GetMapping
    public String showBeerPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("beers", beerService.getAllBeers());
        model.addAttribute("styles", styleService.getAllStyles());
        model.addAttribute("countries", countryService.getAll());
        model.addAttribute("breweries", breweryService.getAll());

        // for receiving user input
        model.addAttribute("beerSearchDto", new BeerSearchDto());
        model.addAttribute("choice");

        return "beers";
    }

@PostMapping("/sort")
    public String sortBeers (@ModelAttribute int choice, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("styles", styleService.getAllStyles());
        model.addAttribute("countries", countryService.getAll());
        model.addAttribute("breweries", breweryService.getAll());
        if (choice == -1) {
            model.addAttribute("beers", beerService.getAllBeers());
        } else if (choice == 1) {
            model.addAttribute("beers", beerService.sortByName());
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            model.addAttribute("beers", beerService.sortByAbv());
        }else if (choice == 3) {
            model.addAttribute("beers", beerService.sortByRating());
        }
        return "beers"; 
    }



<form th:action="@{/beers}" th:object="${choice}" method="post">
                <div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="country-ddb"
                                data-toggle="dropdown"
                                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Sort by:
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <select th:field="${choice}" class="custom-select" >
                            <option class="dropdown-item" th:value="-1"
                                    href="#">Any</option>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" th:value="1"
                               th:text="Name" href="#">Name</option>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" th:value="2"
                               th:text="ABV" href="#">ABV</option>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" th:value="3"
                               th:text="Rating" href="#">Rating</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

My application builds but the view in question does not load, this is exert of what I get

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/beers.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/beers.html]")
```

...

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "beers" - line 173, col 37)
```

...
line 173 is:

```
<select th:field="${choice}" class="custom-select" >
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'choice' available as request attribute
```

Also, I declared `int choice` as a field in my mvc class and initialized it in the constructor. I think I am either not assigning value to choice or not sending it correctly to the mvc controller. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there's any way we can help you.  The error message is telling you that you've got multiple definitions of a bean named `beerController`, and yet that word does not show up anywhere in what you've shown us.  So this particular problem is likely not with anything you've shown here.  Please consider submitting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at least narrow your problem down enough to know yourself that what you're showing us has anything at all to do with the problem.

Comment: As said above the main issue is with passing the value from the dropdown menu to the method in controller. I have edited the question to better represent the issue I am facing. I am striving to submitting well asked questions and learning with every new one.